# Circularity in Class initialization

Tags: java

I was reading something today and came across a statement that said: Lazy instantiation helps avoid harmful circularity in class intialization. What does circularity in Class Instantiation mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Class A in its constructor creates instance of class B, class B creates instance of class C, and class C creates instance of class A.

Comment: I think, what you have described is circularity in "instance initialization". But I think I can relate it to Class initialization also.
Thanks for your answer.